# Find Matches in MySQL by uknown common Words

Tags: php, mysql, sql, multiple-matches

I'm working on a MYSQL table in which i have thousands (20 thousand) of issues reported by users collected in the last 2 years. And now I have to treat this reported issues separately.

The problem I am facing is that many of these reported issues are similar (I mean a lot of them). And I would like to find matches in the the table.

And the problem I'm having here again, is that the "reported issues" are written manually, so they differ from each other. but matches may contain Some common words

So I am wondering if there is a way to find matches in the MySQL table by common words.

What I am trying to do here is to retrieve similar rows (that mach in many keywords) without using any specific keywords

Is there any tool to do that? Is there a way to do that?

I am open also to all kind of php scripts that my work, Thank you in advance

Comment: Not sure if the problem is complex and you did not describe it well or it is just some simple problem but looks like complex... First of all show us some examples of these words or similar words. By writen manually you mean someone writes car and automobile? How would you look for this then? You have to show us more so then we can understand maybe it is better to limit input by some range of tags for the future. But for the present maybe it will need some interesting php code, or depends on the accuracy of this search.

Comment: Thank you @WigglerJtag for your answear, here is what i am looking for exactly
what i am trying to do here is to retirive similar rows (that mach in many keywords) without using any specific keywords
And yes, i think i need some srt of interesting php code :)

Comment: Dont know your programming knowledge, but this is not easy task. First script I would grab all those keywords from DB and look at them how exactly simmilar they are. Then I would decide how to create an array of these words, not sure if there are 1000 or 100000 different words. Then I would use next script for searching fulltext and so on in database. You're not specific so I can't be specific. Reported issues should be at some category, are those films, cars, music and so on, this is what you have to rely on. If u're DB is about cars I would spend a day to creating my own array about cars.

Comment: Thank you again, i have to problems here : first : the "reported issues" tables is still growing up till this hour. Second, and worst :/ My db Can be about everything in the professional world, drugstores, cars, hospitals, Doctors, and really everything else, the only atch keyword i can think about are cities, because each Reported Issue contain a city from a generated table. i see how hard it's really to do what i am looking for

Comment: So reported column can even hold text like 'Hello how are you doing?', and why would you like to match this text, group it? What is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: NO, it cant contain that

Comment: no it cant contain that, it contains things like : Name (of a person or a company) , category , work, city, comment.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start off by asking someone with Domain Knowledge for their absolute top 2 or 3 recurring problems.  They should be able to just reel these off.

Ask them to supply you with the terms and synonyms used in those 2 or 3 main problems, else you will have to do this yourself.

Clone the table and put a [FULLTEXT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) index on it and see how effective fulltext search is in identifying matching issues.

I would be surprised if this does not yield pretty good results from the corpus, but if they are not good enough then you might want to wander into the field of NLP (Natural Language Processing) - a more natural fit for that would be the toolset that you can use with Python though.

Another alternative is to build in some kind of tagging system, but the best ones rely on human intervention and their success depends largely on how well the GUI is built.

Comment: Tank you @cups, i'll try to do what you mentioned above, and i'll let you know right after :)